# "subplot" está dando erro no "title"

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estou tentando rodar um `subplot`,só que está dando erro no `title`(título):

```
> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17364/305905731.py in <module> 4
> graf_dados=df.groupby('lojas_cidade').count().produto_valor.sort_values(ascending=False)
> 5 plt.bar(graf_dados.index,graf_dados.values) ----> 6
> plt.title('Vendas por Loja') 7 plt.xticks(rotation=90) 8 TypeError:
> 'str' object is not callable
```

O que pode ser?

Quando tiro o `title` funciona normalmente.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (10,7))

plt.subplot(2,2,1)
graf_dados=df.groupby('lojas_cidade').count().produto_valor.sort_values(ascending=False)
plt.bar(graf_dados.index,graf_dados.values)
plt.title('Vendas por Loja')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.subplot(2,2,2)
graf_dados=df.groupby('produto_produto').count().produto_valor.sort_values(ascending=False)
plt.bar(graf_dados.index,graf_dados.values)
plt.title('Produtos que mais Vendem')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.subplot(2,2,3)
graf_dados = df[['lojas_cidade','produto_valor']].groupby('lojas_cidade').sum().produto_valor.sort_values(ascending=False)
plt.bar(graf_dados.index,graf_dados.values)
plt.title('Receita por Loja')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.subplot(2,2,4)
graf_dados=df[['produto_produto','produto_valor']].groupby('produto_produto').sum().produto_valor.sort_values(ascending=False)
plt.bar(graf_dados.index,graf_dados.values)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.title=('Receitas por Produto')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Que tipo de erro? Fale mais sobre e se possivel inclua a mensagem de erro na pergunta....

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17364/305905731.py in <module>
      4 graf_dados=df.groupby('lojas_cidade').count().produto_valor.sort_values(ascending=False)
      5 plt.bar(graf_dados.index,graf_dados.values)
----> 6 plt.title('Vendas por Loja')
      7 plt.xticks(rotation=90)
      8 

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Porque é que tem o tag `r` e não `python`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Verifique se em algum código antes, você não está setando o valor de plt.title ao invés de chamá-lo como uma função.

Por exemplo, se houver uma linha do tipo

```py
plt.title = "Título aqui"
```

e subsequentemente for executada uma linha como

```py
plt.title("Outro título aqui")
```

esse erro vai acontecer, pois o nome `title` de `plt` foi *modificado*, tornando-se uma string, então chamá-lo como se ele fosse uma função produz um erro.

Numa situação normal, o nome `title` do Pyplot [é uma função](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.title.html), então a linha que tem erro não fez nada de errado. O erro de fato está em modificar o `title` como se ele fosse uma propriedade. É um erro chato de encontrar, porque a exceção aparece num lugar, mas o *erro de fato* está ocorrendo antes... então você é induzido a procurar problema onde não tem.

Enfim, procure no restante do seu código por linhas como a primeira ali em cima, pois chamar `plt.title` não é um erro. Ele deveria ser uma função, e não uma string.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!! Era isso mesmo tinha um =,difícil achar pq o erro não mostra antes fica difícil né ....    plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.bar(graf_dados.index,graf_dados.values)
plt.title=('Receitas por Produto')

Comment: Fico feliz de ter ajudado! Recomendo marcar a pergunta como resolvida. Também estou curioso porque deram downvote, já que a resposta resolveu o problema... =/

Comment: Estava procurando onde era para marcar,kkk Valeu Parceiro!!!